# block from SSH and FTP

Tags: ssh

yesterday i was upload some images using filezilla to my VPS , 
and today when i tried to login into my VPS i got connection time out , same thing when i tried to access using FTP. but i can acces using another ssh with command ssh user@ips.

im using centos 6.6 and CSF installed, i've tried to add my ip on csf.allow and csf.ignore but nothing change,
i did checked csf.deny and host.deny but nothing there , it was empty.

is there a way to unblock my vps so i can connect with my local ip ?

*edited* my website using cloudflare, may be thats why i can access it.
when i try to use my vps ip address on my browser i also got connection time out.

Comment: Have you checked if something else is blocking you? Is your FTP connection actually reaching the VPS? Do you see log entries?

Comment: So you *can* reach your VPS on port 80(http) and 22(ssh), but you cannot reach it on port 21(ftp) - Did I understand correctly? Why not simply using scp/sftp to transfer your files?

Answer (score 0):

If you can connect to the server with something like `wget http://server/` or `ssh server` the server is up and running.

If you now get `Connection time out` this means there is some kind of firewall somewhere between you and your server simply dropping your attempt. (If the service was not running you would get `Connection refused`.)

To deactivate that firewall you have to find out if that firewall runs on your side, on your servers side, or somewhere in between like at your company or your VPS-provider.

But why do you need any unblocking? You have ssh access to your server this means you can also transfer files using scp or sftp. If that is not enough please update your question.

Comment: if using my ip addres i cant login into ssh nor ftp , i do can login using another vps with ssh command , but the problem is i need to upload some data and yet i got blocked.